# How do I automate mysql queries for each day, whilst using the date as a condition in my query?

Tags: mysql, sql, automated-tests, mysql-workbench

I am working at a company and we are in a situation where we have to do mysql queries each day(for the previous day) to check some numbers. I was assigned to it and have about 10 queries to run each morning. I want to know if there is a way so that I can automate these queries each day. I don't mind logging in to workbench to run all of then at once? Only tricky part is we are using clarion date and since I have to run the queries for the previous day the clarion date will have to increase each day.

An example of one of the queries.

```
select count(*) from item_sales
where code = 12
and date = 79686;
```

This is an older clariondate but that would have to increase with each day.

The expected outcome would preferably be receiving an email everyday.

Comment: I would try with a procedure with event scheduler (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-configuration.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple script which would :

- get the timestamp for the day before
- convert it to clarion date format
- run the SQL queries, fetch the results
- send an email with the results

When it is tested and works, create a simple crontab specifying that you want your script to be ran every day.

Answer (score 0):

You can write below query which takes care of clarion date

```
query="select count(*) from item_sales
where code = 12
and date = DATEDIFF(now(),'1800-12-28')";
```

And you can write shell script or php script and set cronjob to run this query and get result and send mail with result.

Shell example:

```
data=`mysql -u $user --password=$password -e $query`;

echo "Total Count :$data" | mail -s "subject" someone@somewhere.com
```

Comment: with password not encrypted, it's quite a bad idea

Comment: What is cronjob? How do I set that up? Thanks for the datediff functions thats sweet!

Comment: cronjobs or crontab can be set in linux which can schedule your task at perticular time and interval.   https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-tasks-on-a-vps